# Tmux swap window with window to the left

Tags: tmux

I know I can swap windows using `swap-window -d *source* -t *dest*`, but I'd like to be able to swap the current window with the window to the left/right (effectively, 'move' a window left and right through the list). In particular, I want to map this command to a shortcut in my tmux.conf. I think I could do this if there was a way to reference the current window number in the tmux.conf file and do something like this:

`swap-window -t *cur_window -1*`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *tmux* manpage describes the *target-window* syntax accepted by `swap-window`’s `-s` and `-t` options. Specifically, you can use `+` and `-` to refer to the next and previous window numbers.

Thus, you might bind `<` and `>` to move windows left and right like this:

```
bind-key < swap-window -t -
bind-key > swap-window -t +
```

Comment: The latest version of tmux 3.3 has now by default the keybind `Ctrl+B, Shit+,` (or `Ctrl+B, <`) to open a menu to swap window left/right.

Answer (score 7):

Chris's answer is great!

Just some improve:

```
bind-key -r < swap-window -t -
bind-key -r > swap-window -t +
```

Flag -r indicates this key may repeat. This is may more convenient.